# AChartEngine graph won't show up?

Tags: android, achartengine

I have been using AChartEngine for a few weeks now, and as of last week everything was working fine. I really cannot find what I have changed, but now the graph just doesn't appear on my screen. My `Activity` initializes with an empty Layout attribute for the graph. At a certain point, the user reads in input and then the graph is updated.

Here is the XML code for my graph:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/eti1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="11" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wavesOptions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="8" >


        <!-- 

        Unrelated spinners/checkboxes

        -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/graphScroll"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/wavesOptions"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/graph1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is a picture of my layout as shown in Eclipse. The box outlined in blue at the top of my view is where my graph would be going. It looks small, but I use `wrap_content` for height, so it should match its parent. When I set the graph to that view in my java code, nothing cahnges at all. All of the checkboxes are updated and a new spinner is added correctly.

[image]

Below is my code from my .java file:

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView( R.layout.waves );

    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer( 2 ); 

}
```

Once the user calls for the information to graph, data is stored in an array called `waveResults` and the method `updateGraph()` is called. The important part where the graphView is set to the layout is all the way at the bottom:

```
public void updateGraph() {
    int num = 166;
    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer( 2 );
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // NetV1
    netV1Series = new XYSeries( "Net V1", 0 );
    // NetV2
    netV2Series = new XYSeries( "Net V2", 0 );
    // NetV3  
    netV3Series = new XYSeries( "Net V3", 0 );
    // VDI1
            // VDI2
            // VDI3
    if( spinnerChoice == 0 ) {
        vdi1Series = new XYSeries( "Diff V1", 1 );
        vdi2Series = new XYSeries( "Diff V2", 1 );
        vdi3Series = new XYSeries( "Diff V3", 1 );
    } else {
        vdi1Series = new XYSeries( "Curr 1", 1 );
        vdi2Series = new XYSeries( "Curr 2", 1 );
        vdi3Series = new XYSeries( "Curr 3", 1 );
    }

    dataset.addSeries( netV1Series );
    dataset.addSeries( netV2Series );
    dataset.addSeries( netV3Series );
    dataset.addSeries( vdi1Series );
    dataset.addSeries( vdi2Series );
    dataset.addSeries( vdi3Series );
    netV1Renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    netV1Renderer.setColor( Color.WHITE );
    netV2Renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    netV2Renderer.setColor( Color.YELLOW );
    netV3Renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    netV3Renderer.setColor( Color.BLUE );
    vdi1Renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    vdi1Renderer.setColor( Color.RED );
    vdi2Renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    vdi2Renderer.setColor( Color.CYAN );
    vdi3Renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    vdi3Renderer.setColor( Color.GRAY );
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer( netV1Renderer );
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer( netV2Renderer );
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer( netV3Renderer );
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer( vdi1Renderer );
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer( vdi2Renderer );
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer( vdi3Renderer );     

    renderer.setAxesColor( Color.DKGRAY );
    renderer.setPointSize( 14 );
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor( true );
    renderer.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLACK );
    renderer.setMarginsColor( Color.BLACK );
    renderer.setChartTitle( "Waves" );
    renderer.setShowGrid( true );
    renderer.setXLabels( 10 );
    renderer.setYLabels( 7 );
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible( false );
    renderer.setPanEnabled( false, false );
    renderer.setZoomEnabled( false, false );
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, Color.WHITE);

    if( spinnerChoice == 0 ) {
        renderer.setYTitle("Diff Volts", 1);
    } else {
        renderer.setYTitle( "Current", 1 );
    }
    renderer.setYTitle( "Net Volts", 0 );

    renderer.setYAxisAlign( Align.LEFT, 0 );
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);


    graphLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.graph1 );
    graphLayout.removeAllViews();
    Log.i( "GRAPH", "After Remove" );
    graphView = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView( getApplicationContext(), dataset, renderer, 0.3f);
    Log.i( "GRAPH",  "Before addView" );
    graphLayout.addView(graphView);
    Log.i( "GRAPH", "After addView" );
}
```

At the end of the `updateGraph()` method the three `Log` calls are all displayed in my LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `ScrollView`. I have only removed the `ScrollView` from your layout and the chart displayed fine.

Note the warning at the `ScrollView` in the waves.xml in edit mode: "This ScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless".

Comment: Is there any more of an explanation to why it wasn't working? I know it doesn't make sense to have the ScrollLayout as it does nothing, but how did this prevent the graph displaying within its child?

Comment: I haven't used ScrollView much, but the combination between the layout, the ScrollView with a height="wrap_content" and a chart doesn't sounds like the best one.